# Mean value theorem and random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(Z_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a (stationary) sequence of real valued random variables with finite variance where $Z_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Further let $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a another sequence of random variables with $\operatorname{Var}(r_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Now we fix $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ and define $f(x):=P(Z_i\leq x,Z_j\leq x)$. We assume further that $f$ is differentiable.

I'm interested in deriving an equation for $f(x-r_l)=P(Z_i\leq x-r_l,Z_j\leq x-r_l)$ with the following form:
$$f(x-r_l)=f(x)+something.$$ I know that for $something=f(x-r_l)-f(x)$ I have an equation of the form above but that doesn't help.

My professor told me that by the Mean value Theorem we can write
$$f(x-r_l)=f(x)-r_l f'(\xi),$$where $0\leq|\xi|\leq|r_l|$, which I find really confusing then the left hand side of the last equation is a real number and the right side would be a random variable which doesn't make any sense to me.

By the Mean value theorem we obtain for all $\omega\in\Omega$ that
$$f(x-r_l(\omega))=f(x)-r_l(\omega) f'(\xi(\omega)),$$with $0\leq|\xi(\omega)|\leq|r_l(\omega)|$. But that's something different and I don't get an estimate for $f(x-r_l)$.

So, does anyone knows how to proceed from here to get a result similar to that one my professor told me? And does anyone know how my professor could have meant his statement?

Final  note: My professor actually defined $f(x,y):=P(Z_i\leq x,Z_j\leq y)$ and used the Mean value theorem for functions in two variables which should make no difference.

I would be really thankful about any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: The left hand side of the equation is not deterministic, it is random as it is a function of the random variable $r_l$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It holds that $f(x-r_l)=P(Z_i\leq x-r_l,Z_j\leq x-r_l)=P(Z_i+r_l\leq x,Z_j+r_l\leq x)$ and that's a real number since it's only the probability of the set $\{\omega\in\Omega:Z_i(\omega)+r_l(\omega)\leq x\}\cap\{\omega\in\Omega:Z_j(\omega)+r_l(\omega)\leq x\}$. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @stroem: I agree with Bunder.  $f(x)$ is function which takes a real number and gives another real number (in fact a probability).  But if you apply it to a random variable, then it gives you another random variable.  I suspect your second expression might be $E_{r_l}[f(x-r_l)]$

Comment: In Brockwell and Davis "Time Series: Theory and Applications (2nd Ed.)"Proposition 6.1.5. states: Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n=x+O_p(b_n)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<b_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. If $f$ is a function with s derivatives at $a$ then $$f(X_n)=\sum_{j=0}^s \frac{f^{(j)}(x)}{j!}(X_n-x)^j+o_p(b_n^s),$$ where $f^{(j)}$ is the $j$th derivative of $f$ and $f^0=f$. That's not exactly what my professsor stated but it's quite similar.